# 3D printer file type support

Tags: file-format, 3d-printing, conversion, compatibility

For Blender 2.70, I'm trying to figure out:

- Which 3D printer file formats Blender natively supports
- Which 3D printer file formats Blender can support with the use of plugins/extensions/etc.
- Which 3D printer file formats can be converted into another format that works with Blender
- Which 3D printer file formats Blender cannot support at all, ever

The most important one of those is the last one (which file types can Blender not import/export/modify at all). Can someone point me to any documentation or help me figure out which file formats fall into which group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender supports the [STL (STereoLithography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29) format which is supported by all printers and considered as standard for prototyping.

Shapeways for example supports the file types: STL, OBJ, X3D, Collada or VRML97/2.

Blender comes with support of STL, OBJ, X3D and Collada.

- [Documentation on import formats](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Import)
- [Documentation on export formats](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Files/Export)

When there is a public demand for a specific file format someone will create an import / export addon for it.

Comment: Thanks @stacker (I'd upvote you if I had the rep to do so) - if STL is a standard for prototyping, what file format is considered "viable for production" (and, does Blender support that format)? Thanks again!

Comment: @Venkat I'm not an expert on 3D printing. I just created a model and uploaded it to several sites which provide print services and all of them supported STL. This might be interesting: http://www.3dprinting-forums.com/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=6844